# Apache Flink checkpoints keep failing

Tags: apache-flink

I am running flink in a containerized environment on windows for development and testing. When deploying the job to the cluster all checkpoints begin to fail regardless of the state backend i use. Below you can see screenshots of the configuration and the failures, This has been tested with high, low and zero data throughput and it always fails. The server logs simply show it expired before completing

[image]

[image]

Comment: A likely explanation is that the machines in the cluster are unable to write to the distributed filesystem you've configured to store the checkpoints. Maybe tell us more about that part of the setup.

Comment: This cluster is running purely on the local development environment, in terms that of the file system, it is purely trying to write these checkpoints to the local disk, a mapped volume to the container.

Comment: Seems to be that there was a glitch with docker (or good old windows...) restarting the docker runtime resolved the issue using the same mapped file location. Seems strange that flink doesnt report an IO error when it cant write the checkpoint files